# gitlab : prevent push to a public branch without MR approval

Tags: gitlab, githooks

We are using **gitlab** free version along with **jenkins** for cicd

In our context, 'development' is the public (and protected) branch which is sane at anytime

I tried looking at a few related questions but didnt find. We have a development branch from where users create branches for features and bugfixes (the usual workflow)
Users create MR and link it to a branch they created (say, bugfix-xxxxx)
Once the MR is approved, this will be merged to develop.
So, normal workflow has no problem
However, when a user accidentally pushes from development branch, theis is also getting pushed directly to develop .

What is the best way to prevent such commits (to development branch) which are not approved and not part of any approved MR?
Is it a git admin push pre-hook? any resources to refer to ? any scripts to do achieve this? etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent this from happening.

In **Settings -> Repository -> Protected branches** You should not allow developers to push.

[image]